# What is this bash snippet doing? PHP/perl equivalent?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand what this code snippet is doing. It's the bash syntax that I can't quite figure out.

```
# Static function
get_ofuscated_link() {
local VAR=$1
local I N C R

I=0
N=${#VAR}
while (( I < N )); do
    C=$((16#${VAR:$I:2} + 0x18))
    R="$R"$(printf \\$(($C/64*100+$C%64/8*10+$C%8)))
    (( I += 2 ))
done
echo "$R"
}
```

It is called by this command

```
JS_VAR=$(echo "$PAGE" |  parse 'function[[:space:]]*_' '"\([^"]\+\)";' 1) || return
FILE_URL=$(get_ofuscated_link "$JS_VAR" | parse_attr href) || return
```

Just wondering what the Colon's do within the `C=$` line and what the R= line means.

Also does `function[[:space:]]*_` have a specific meaning in bash or is that just a straight string it is looking through.

The source file comes from [plowshare](http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/source/browse/src/modules/mediafire.sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colons are part of the `${parameter:offset:length}` notation, bash's version of a substring function. `${VAR:$I:2}` would translate into perl as `substr($VAR, $I, 2)`. The whole `C=` assignment is equivalent to

```
$C = hex(substr($VAR, $I, 2) + 0x18);
```

So `$VAR` is a string of hex digits, and the loop takes them two at a time, adds the magic number 0x18, and stores that into $C.

The `R=` line is simple enough. First of all, its top-level structure is:

```
R="$R"stuff
```

which simply appends some stuff to the string `$R`. Now let's look at the stuff. Its core is:

```
$(($C/64*100+$C%64/8*10+$C%8)))
```

which would be exactly the same in perl, without the `$((...))` around it. The dollar-sign-double-parentheses is the shell's "arithmetic expansion" operator. If you study the formula you'll see that it converts `$C` to a three-digit octal number (the digits are `$C/64`, `$C%64/8`, and `$C%8`) and then converts that to a decimal number with the same three digits. So this is just a weird way of taking the number in `$C` and printing it as octal.

Now that we have that worked out, the stuff being appended to `$R` is:

```
$(printf \\000)
```

where the octal digits replace the 000. This is equivalent to perl's `chr(oct("000"))`.

So `$R` is being built as a string with one character for each pair of hex digits in the input `$VAR`, which represents a string of character codes which are obfuscated by having 0x18 subtracted from them, and this function adds the 0x18 back on.

The `[[:space:]]` operator is part of a regular expression. It's a POSIX equivalent to perl's `\s` operator that matches various kinds of whitespace. We'd have to see your `parse` command or function to know for sure, but it looks like the regular expression has something to do with finding function definitions in a javascript source file.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can select a substring of a parameter:

```
x=hello
y=${x:2:2}   # y = ll
```

the while loop is iterating over 2-digit chunks of `VAR`. Inside the arithmetic expansion construct `$(( ... ))`, "16#string" is the notation to treat `string` as a base-16 number.

The R line performs some arithmetic on `C` and appends the result to the previous value of `R`.

Answer (score 1):

It is converting the URL into an obfuscated notation, as its name suggests (though there's a typo in the name, further obfuscating everything).

```
for (i = 0; i < length(url); i += 2)
{
     c = hex value of two characters of URL + 0x18
     r += character c interpreted as octal
}
```

So, given `1234`, the output is `*L`.  The `*` comes from 0x12 + 0x18 = 0x2A = 42<sub>10</sub> = 052 = '`*`'.  The 'L' comes from 0x34 + 0x18 = 0x4C = 76<sub>10</sub> = 0114 = '`L`'.